# How to install a driver for Integrated Graphic UHD 750?

Tags: drivers, gpu, integrated

I have a core i7 11700K CPU that comes with UHD 750 integrated graphic. Below is the result of `sudo lshw -c video` command:

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:141 memory:91000000-91ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

How can I make ubuntu recognize the UHD 750 graphic? I have ubuntu 20.04 and `5.11.0-40-generic` kernel.

Comment: Why do you believe you need to install something?  Is something not working?  Can you provide more details about the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: You already have "installed" *i915* kernel module/driver. Which problem do you have? Please also show an output of `vainfo` (if not installed, install it with `sudo apt-get install vainfo` first).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between integrated and discrete graphic cards?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/805509/what-is-the-difference-between-integrated-and-discrete-graphic-cards)

Comment: How can I test if my integrated graphic is working?

Comment: It is working if you can see something on your monitor.